# Keep a dialog on screen on onPause in Android

Tags: android

I have an Android app, that is using the SIM Toolkit. The application has a screen, that shows a dialog, that should be visible in the background when the SIM toolkit becomes focused.

Right now, when the SIM Toolkit gains the focus, the dialog dissapears, as is the Android way, and is reinstantiated upon `onResume()`. How do I keep the dialog in the background visible?

If I understand the process correctly, once the app receives the `onPause` command, it is rendered as an Image, and that is used as the background for the other app, if it uses a transparent background. Maybe there is a way to tell the process to also capture the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is something that should have been obvious to me, but somehow still eluded my notice.

Dialogs, as far as you create them using the `showDialog()`, `dismissDialog()` and `removeDialog()` are taken care of by the OS.

I was confused, and thought that I had to take care of them myself, thus introducing this bug in my app. Fixed now!